# Como fazer uma soma cumulativa no BigQuery?

Tags: sql, query, count, soma, bigquery

Estou precisando criar um dashboard a partir de uma query. Eu gostaria de gerar essa coluna na query sempre somando ao mês anterior, ou seja, uma soma cumulativa.

ex:
ao invés de:

```
mês 1: 2
mês 2: 3 
mês 3: 5
mês 4: 1
```

seria:

```
mês 1: 2
mês 2: 5
mês 3: 10
mês 4: 11
```

No meu caso:

```
SELECT count(id_produto) AS quantidade_ofertas, date_trunc(cast(datahora as date), month) as mes
FROM `TABELA1` 
WHERE DATE(process_time) < CURRENT_DATE()
and cast(datahora as date) < CURRENT_DATE()
group by date_trunc(cast(datahora as date), month)
```

Sendo que nesse código acima, gera uma coluna com valores para cada mês, e não a soma ao anterior (cumulativa).

A ideia dessa query é gerar um dashboard onde eu possa filtrar por data sem que o 'acumulativo' que a ferarmente fornece, atrapalhe.

Comment: não seria só trocar o `count()` pelo `sum()`?

Comment: Não.

O sum somaria os ids do produto. O que tentei foi fazer com with:

SELECT count(id_produto) AS quantidade_ofertas, date_trunc(cast(datahora as date), month) as mes
FROM `TABELA1` 
WHERE DATE(process_time) < CURRENT_DATE()
and cast(datahora as date) < CURRENT_DATE()
group by date_trunc(cast(datahora as date), month)
SELECT sum(quantidade_ofertas) as cumulativo, mes
from TAB1
group by quantidade_ofertas, mes
order by mes asc

Só que dá o mesmo resultado, porque ele soma os meses iguais. Eu quero que some sempre o mês anterior.

Comment: Poderia fazer composição de função, estou sem o bigquery pra testar, mas então vc faria um sum(count(id_produto))

Comment: Retorno: Aggregations of aggregations are not allowed at [1:8]

Comment: Parece que o que você quer é usar uma window function: https://cloud.google.com/dataprep/docs/html/Window-Functions_57344749

Answer (score -1):

Eu acho que para o seu problema, você pode dividir isso em 2 partes, primeiro usando `groupby` para achar os ids em cada mes, e depois usando `over` para fazer a soma cumulativa. Segue um exemplo

```
with t1 as (
  select '2020-01-01' as data, 0101 as id_produto
  union all
  select '2020-01-01', 0102
  union all
  select '2020-02-01', 0201
  union all
  select '2020-02-01', 0202
  union all
  select '2020-02-01', 0203
  union all
  select '2020-03-01', 0301
  union all
  select '2020-03-01', 0302
  union all
  select '2020-03-01', 0303
),

t2 as (
  select 
    date_trunc(cast(data as date),  month) as data,
    count(id_produto) as id_produto
  from t1 
  group by 1
)

select
  data,
  sum(id_produto) over (order by data rows between unbounded preceding and current row)
from t2
--saida:
Linha   data       f0_  
1       2020-01-01 2
2       2020-02-01 5
3       2020-03-01 8
```

Answer (score -1):

Tente fazer um COUNT com PARTITION BY e ORDER BY assim:

```
SELECT 
    count(id_produto) OVER (PARTITION BY mes ORDER BY mes ASC) AS quantidade_ofertas, 
    date_trunc(cast(datahora as date), month) as mes

FROM `TABELA1` 

WHERE DATE(process_time) < CURRENT_DATE()
    and cast(datahora as date) < CURRENT_DATE()

group by date_trunc(cast(datahora as date), month)
```

não tenho certeza se o Bigquery vai reconhecer o alis *mes*, então talvez funcione assim:

```
SELECT 
    count(id_produto) OVER (PARTITION BY date_trunc(cast(datahora as date), month) ORDER BY date_trunc(cast(datahora as date), month) ASC) AS quantidade_ofertas, 
    date_trunc(cast(datahora as date), month) as mes

FROM `TABELA1` 

WHERE DATE(process_time) < CURRENT_DATE()
    and cast(datahora as date) < CURRENT_DATE()

group by date_trunc(cast(datahora as date), month)
```